# I can't change the text color of the boolean checkbox in Vuetify (version -> nuxtjs/vuetify: "0.5.5")

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am creating a website using nuxt.js and vuetify and I want to change the color of the boolean checkbox's text to black which is by default white, see [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#radios-default)! How can I change the color?

I have already tried using the class `black--text`

Here is some code which I have written:

```html
<v-container>
    <v-form
        ref="form"
        v-model="valid"
        lazy-validation
      >
        <p>{{ radios || 'null' }}</p>
        <v-radio-group v-model="radios" :mandatory="true">
          <v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1" class="black--text" />
          <v-radio label="Radio 2" value="radio-2" class="black--text" />
        </v-radio-group>
      </v-form>
</v-container>
```

And here's the script for it

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      radios: 'radio-1',
      valid: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I expected the color of the radio's text to be black but it is still white.

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43299408/64483861-a4aefe00-d227-11e9-8589-50b41df1d499.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to do this with props as the documentation provide [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#radios-colors).

So, another solution is to use [vue.js deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) in vue single file component:

```html
<template>
<v-radio label="Radio 1" value="radio-1" class="black--text" />
</template>

<style scoped>
.black--text /deep/ label {
    color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is just changing the color of the radio circle but I want to change the color of the text.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: what if im using lang="scss"

Answer (score 2):

Add label onto the slot

```
<v-radio>
  <span slot="label" class="red--text">My label</span>
</v-radio>
```

Works on Vue 2, Vuetify 2.3